# Proving the uniqueness of zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let's assume that $(X, \mathbb{F})$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. How could we prove that zero vector $\vec{0}\in X$ is unique?

**Prop:** $\vec{0}\in X$ is unique in $X$.

**Pf:** Zero vector $\vec{0}\in X$ is a vector in $X$ such that for every $\vec{x}\in X$, $\vec{x}+\vec{0} = \vec{0}+\vec{x} = \vec{x}$. Let's assume that $\theta(x)\in X$ is another vector in $X$ that satisfies the same conditions. Then, $\vec{0} = \vec{0}+\vec{0}$, and if $\vec{0}\in X$ is zero vector, $\vec{0}+\vec{0}(x) = \vec{0}(x)$, leading us to $\vec{0} = \vec{0}(x)$. Thus, $\vec{0}\in X$ is unique.

Does my proof make sense?

Comment: Why ask and answer a question at the same time?

Comment: I would like to make my proofs accessible to future MO users, while also trying to hear people's thoughts about them. Although I'm not sure if this is a reasonable thing to do here.

Comment: You should move your answer into your question so that you can show your effort. As it stands, your question shows a lack of effort and your answer shows that you need help.

Comment: How does my answer show that I need help? That is essentially the same proof you came up with, except I assumed $\vec{x} + \vec{0} = \vec{x}+\vec{0}(x)$

Comment: Side note: you'll notice this proof is very similar to the proof of uniqueness of the identity in groups, 0 and 1 in rings (when it exists), etc. Proof of uniqueness often follows the "assume there are two such objects, and prove they are the same" route, so this is typically a good place to start.

Comment: @Tom Does my proof make sense as well?

Comment: If you have two zero vectors $\vec 0$ and $\theta$, how do you know that $\vec x-\vec x=\vec 0$?

Comment: That's definitely not the most unreasonable thing to want to do, but this isn't the best way to go about it, especially for such an elementary statement. If you want to show off a proof, you should try to search for a similar previously posted question and post your proof there (if it's not already there). If you don't find anything, you could add your proof to your question and ask people to critique it ("Is this right? Can this be shorter?"), or ask for alternate proofs of the claim ("Is there any other way to prove this?").

Comment: Yeah, it should have been replaced as zero vector.

Comment: I do appreciate you wanting to contribute, and you should keep trying to do it. Taking a look at the rules and best practices for how to ask and answer questions should help you get the hang of how this place works pretty quickly. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, sure! Thanks for your so valuable thoughts.

Comment: Yes. Part of an abbreviated definition of vector space is that vector addition forms a commutative group. We prove the uniqueness of the two-sided identity of any group in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Let $0$ and $0'$ be two zero vectors.

Then $0=0+0'$ because $0'$ is a zero vector.

But $0+0'=0'$ because $0$ is a zero vector.

Therefore, $0=0'$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$$\vec x+\vec \theta=\vec x+\vec 0=\vec x,$$
then
$-\vec x+\vec x+\vec\theta=-\vec x+\vec x+\vec 0$,
hencefore $$\vec\theta=\vec 0.$$